# How to work with large bitmap. Rotating and inserting to the gallery

Tags: android, image, memory, camera

I need to take a picture with the camera and, if depending on the picture size, rotate it before saving it into the gallery.

I'm using

> Intent imageCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
>      imageCaptureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
>      startActivityForResult(imageCaptureIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);

To take the pic and save it to a temporary file.

Then

> Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
>      String str = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(cr, bmp, name, description);

To save it.

This is the code i have tried to use to rotate the bitmap

> Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
>      matrix.postRotate(180);
>      Bitmap x = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix,    true);
>      android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(cr, x, name, description);

The problem is I'm getting an OutOfMemoryException.

Is there a better way to handle the bitmaps to avoid breaking the memory?

~Thanks in advance, regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a better way to handle bitmaps.  You could try to parse data directly from a file as Byte[] a portion at a time, and manipulating it in pieces; it's hard and you'll probably end up with very ugly code.

I also suggest the following:

- Use `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(cr, imagePath, name, description)` instead of `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(cr, bmp, name, description)` this way there is no need to call `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath)` and no bitmap will be loaded into memory at that point.
- Throughout your code, make sure no bitmap is loaded unless needed.  Set bitmaps that are no longer needed to `null` and call the garbage collector, or use `bmp.recycle()`.

Comment: bmp.recycle() wont help here cuz you can actually do it right AFTER you catch OOM. I mean after rotating bitmap and saving it. However the OOM most probably comes at rotating moment since it has to keep 2 same bitmaps in RAM there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with rotating bitmap. The problem here:

```
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath); //this is the image you want to rotate
    // keeping in mind that you want to rotate the whole original image instead
    // of its downscaled copy you cant use BitmapFactory downscaling ratio
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(180);
    Bitmap x = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true); 
    // the line above creates another bitmap so we have here 2 same sized bitmaps
    // even using the same var (bmp instead of x) wont change anything here
    // so you gonna get the OOM here
```

is that it creates 2 bitmaps so they want x2 more RAM.
Check [my question and solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641135/how-to-avoid-outofmemory-ex-while-rotating-the-image). I bet for ImageMagick lib.